# How to merge two dataframe where one dataframe has the start time/end time and the other dataframe has the timestamp data

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two dataframe, one with start/end time and the other one with the timestamp data.

```
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| Features | DateTime            | Value |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| A        | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 4     |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| A        | 2020-01-01 00:00:01 | 4.5   |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| A        | 2020-01-01 00:00:02 | 4.3   |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| A        | 2020-01-01 00:00:03 | 4.1   |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| B        | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 30    |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| B        | 2020-01-01 00:00:01 | 31    |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| B        | 2020-01-01 00:00:02 | 35    |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| B        | 2020-01-01 00:00:03 | 40    |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| B        | 2020-01-01 00:00:04 | 41    |
+----------+---------------------+-------+

+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | start               | end                 | location |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 1  | 01/01/2020 00:00:00 | 01/01/2020 00:00:02 | loc1     |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 1  | 01/01/2020 00:00:02 | 01/01/2020 00:00:03 | loc2     |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2  | 01/01/2020 00:00:03 | 01/01/2020 00:00:04 | loc1     |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

And I would like to merge into something like this..

```
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| id | datetime         | a   | b  | loc1 | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1/1/2020 0:00:00 | 4   | 30 | loc1 | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1/1/2020 0:00:01 | 4   | 31 | loc1 | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1/1/2020 0:00:02 | 4.3 | 35 | loc1 | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1/1/2020 0:00:03 | 4.1 | 40 | na   | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| 2  | 1/1/2020 0:00:03 | na  | 40 | na   | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
| 2  | 1/1/2020 0:00:04 | na  | 41 | na   | loc2 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------+------+
```

So, sometimes there are going to be overlaps where id 2 will start in the middle of id 1. Please advise on how you solve this! Thanks!

Comment: can you explain bit more. how you wanna merge?

Comment: in your merged data how you are getting the both loc1 and loc2 it should be loc1 only

Comment: Not sure how your expected result is constructed from your input data sets. As @Pygirl suggested, please update your sample data sets

Answer (score 1):

**Creating your Dataframe:**

```
d = ["2020-01-01 00:00:00" , "2020-01-01 00:00:01", "2020-01-01 00:00:02", "2020-01-01 00:00:03", "2020-01-01 00:00:00",\
"2020-01-01 00:00:01","2020-01-01 00:00:02" , "2020-01-01 00:00:03", "2020-01-01 00:00:04"] 
f = ['A', 'A' , 'A', 'A' , 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B']
val = [4,4.5,4.3,4.1,30,31,35,40,41]

df = pd.DataFrame([f,d,val]).T
df.rename(columns = {0:'Features', 1:'DateTime', 2:'Value'}, inplace = True)
# df.columnns = ['Features', 'DateTime', 'Value']
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df.Value = pd.to_numeric(df.Value, errors='coerce')

df
```

---

**df:**

```
    Features    DateTime    Value
0   A   2020-01-01 00:00:00 4.0
1   A   2020-01-01 00:00:01 4.5
2   A   2020-01-01 00:00:02 4.3
3   A   2020-01-01 00:00:03 4.1
4   B   2020-01-01 00:00:00 30.0
5   B   2020-01-01 00:00:01 31.0
6   B   2020-01-01 00:00:02 35.0
7   B   2020-01-01 00:00:03 40.0
8   B   2020-01-01 00:00:04 41.0
```

---

```
s = ["01/01/2020 00:00:00", "01/01/2020 00:00:02", "01/01/2020 00:00:03"]
e = ["01/01/2020 00:00:02", "01/01/2020 00:00:03", "01/01/2020 00:00:04"]
lo = ['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc1']
idd = [1,1,2]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([idd,s,e,lo]).T
df1.rename(columns = {0:'id', 1:'start', 2:'end',3:'location'}, inplace = True)

df1['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start'])
df1['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end'])
df1
```

---

**df1:**

```
    id  start               end                 location
0   1   2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 00:00:02 loc1
1   1   2020-01-01 00:00:02 2020-01-01 00:00:03 loc2
2   2   2020-01-01 00:00:03 2020-01-01 00:00:04 loc1
```

## Solution:

```
df_up = df.pivot_table(index='DateTime', columns='Features', values='Value')
df_up = df_up.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
df_up
```

---

**df_up:**

```
DateTime                A   B
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00 4.0 30.0
1   2020-01-01 00:00:01 4.5 31.0
2   2020-01-01 00:00:02 4.3 35.0
3   2020-01-01 00:00:03 4.1 40.0
4   2020-01-01 00:00:04 NaN 41.0
```

---

```
df1_new = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': pd.date_range(row.start, row.end, freq='s'),
               'id': row.id,'location': row.location}, columns=['id', 'DateTime', 'location']) 
           for i, row in df1.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)
df1_new
```

---

**df1_new:**

```
    id  DateTime            location
0   1   2020-01-01 00:00:00 loc1
1   1   2020-01-01 00:00:01 loc1
2   1   2020-01-01 00:00:02 loc1
3   1   2020-01-01 00:00:02 loc2
4   1   2020-01-01 00:00:03 loc2
5   2   2020-01-01 00:00:03 loc1
6   2   2020-01-01 00:00:04 loc1
```

---

```
df1_up = df1_new.groupby(['id','DateTime']).apply(
        lambda g: pd.Series(g['location'].values)
    ).unstack().reset_index()
df1_up.rename(columns = {0:'loc1',1:'loc2'},inplace=True)
df1_up
```

---

**df1_up:**

```
    id  DateTime            loc1    loc2
0   1   2020-01-01 00:00:00 loc1    NaN
1   1   2020-01-01 00:00:01 loc1    NaN
2   1   2020-01-01 00:00:02 loc1    loc2
3   1   2020-01-01 00:00:03 loc2    NaN
4   2   2020-01-01 00:00:03 loc1    NaN
5   2   2020-01-01 00:00:04 loc1    NaN
```

---

```
df_res = (pd.merge(df_up, df1_up, on = "DateTime", how='left'))
df_res
```

---

**df_res:**

```
    DateTime            A   B      id   loc1    loc2
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00 4.0 30.0    1   loc1    NaN
1   2020-01-01 00:00:01 4.5 31.0    1   loc1    NaN
2   2020-01-01 00:00:02 4.3 35.0    1   loc1    loc2
3   2020-01-01 00:00:03 4.1 40.0    1   loc2    NaN
4   2020-01-01 00:00:03 4.1 40.0    2   loc1    NaN
5   2020-01-01 00:00:04 NaN 41.0    2   loc1    NaN
```

Comment: You can change the columns name and order and datetime format